# adding CSS to rails form helper

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I would like to add a css class to a rails form helper. The css class is intended to be used in a div around the input tag, though. That's why no style is applied to the slider, I guess.

Original syntax inside form:

```
<div class="range range--light">
          <input type="range" data-init="auto" id="slider3" min="0" max="100" value="<%= @subproject_value1 %>" step="1">
          <output for="slider3">0</output>
</div>
```

[markup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4k7Y3.png)

Rails form helper inside form tag:

```
<%= range_field(:subproject, :ans1, in: 1..100, :class => "range range--light") %>
```

[form helper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNZGt.png)

EDIT:
added images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need that div around the input, then you can simply mark it up in your template and have the actual form helper within it:

```
<div class="range range--light">
    <%= range_field(:subproject, :ans1, in: 1..100, id: 'slider3'%>
    <output for="slider3">0</output>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could have regular markup in form tags.
It still doesn't style it, though.

Comment: I am not sure what library you are using for the styling. Did you make sure the css and js files are both in the asset pipeline and appear in the debugging console as sources? Also if there is JS involved, you might need to initiate it first. This is hard to find without really having more information.

Comment: It's a custom internal libary. All assets are in the proper directories and show up as sources in debug.

Comment: Any chance you can post the assets here?

Comment: So, from what I can see from the css is that most likely there is some JS involved to create the internal range-replacement markup. In your console if you inspect the field, you should be able to see a div with class "range-container". Otherwise you are simply missing out the JS.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add `:'data-init' => 'auto'` to the `range_field` tag